# Rails 3.2 download file when remote form submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this remote form on a static page.

```
<%= form_tag(reports_products_path, :method => "post", :action => "products", :remote => true)  do%>
   <%= submit_tag "Generate Product Report" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller action fired when that form is submitted:

```
def products
  @products = Product.joins(:client).all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf
    format.js do
      pdf = PrintedProductPdf.new(@products)
      File.open("public/product_report/product#{Date.today}.pdf", "wb") { |f| f << pdf.render }
      send_data pdf.render, 
        file_name: "public/product_report/product#{Date.today}.pdf",
        :type => "application/pdf", 
        :disposition => "attachment"
  end
end
```

end

The file writes when the form link is clicked.  However I want the ability to download the file when the submit button in the form is clicked.  The send data function seems to be sending the attachment to lala land

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code for your method.

```
def products
  @products = Product.joins(:client).all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf
    format.js do
      pdf = PrintedProductPdf.new(@products)
      send_data pdf.render,
                :disposition => "attachment; filename=product_#{Date.today.to_s}.pdf",
                :type => "application/pdf"
    end
  end
end
```

PS I throw out saving pdf file to public directory, cause it seems that you create it only for  download link.